# Remove flicker, crop and upscale in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I spent one full day on `ffmpeg` line commands by searching a lot on google but could not achieve what I wanted to and therefore I came here to seek some advice.
I have a video `testinput.mpg` which I believe is a `mpeg-2` video. It is of `720x576` dimensions having `25 fps` and a total bitrate of `4224 kbps`

First problem is that the exported footage is flickering which I wasn't able to remove using ffmpeg with lots of commands I tried like adjusting brightness, contrast, hue, saturation and all.

Second problem was to extract the center portion which I was able to do it with the crop feature using following command.

```
ffmpeg -i testinput.mpg -filter:v "crop=468:374" testoutput.mpg
```

But after cropping I observed that that bitrate fell from `4224 kbps` to `761 kbps` and I assume this has reduced the quality of video.

What I want to achieve is:

1. Crop the video properly keeping the same quality (`acodec copy` `vcodec copy`) -> ffmpeg did not allow me to do both the things together (cropping and having same codec)
2. Remove the flicker from video and upscale it to 4K or HD quality so that it looks nice on big televison (preferably 4K)

I request some help on how to achieve the desired result. Can someone shed some light on it?

Here are 10 seconds sample videos on google drive that I am working on

[testinput.mpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H4iaqX_LJwQE3qc93xyMRALs9X8fB8O1/view?usp=sharing)

[testoutput.mpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14pURx4_70rmaQ4vZfn4VWk4o3XYhOv6G/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Comment: Does the TV upscale automatically? If it does there is no need to upscale.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, TV upscales automatically but I observe quality loss and the flickering and the shadows around the text is prominently visible with a big font. Is the commandline correct? I am not sure if it keeps the codes same in the output. If the desired output is not possible in ffmpeg then its ok but help me with removing the flicker... its very disturbing... Thanks

Comment: Upscaling is not going to make it hav ea higher quality. It is not possible to give it higher quality. So upscaling with ffmpeg won't look better than the TVs auto upscaling. Have you ever zoomed into a JPG beyond 1x? It looks bad. Upscaling is doing the same thing.

Comment: Yes I understand... its like damaging the pixels. any thoughts on removing the flicker?

Comment: Does de-interlacing with yadif filter make it look better? `ffmpeg -i testinput.mpg -filter:v "yadif,crop=468:374" -q:v 3 -c:a copy testoutput.mpg`

Comment: hey... it has improved the quality and definitely looks better. However, not to my satisfaction. Is yadif the only filter available for de-interlacing? Is it possible to tweak the values a bit to get the best output? Thanks

Comment: There is also bwdif and w3fdif. See [filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) for options and values for each filter. `yadif=mode=1` may look better, depending on the content.

Comment: Thanks for showing me direction. It will take some time for me to do some try and test. Please answer this question so that I will accept it. One last question - can you pls help me with a perfect commandline to convert the mpeg file to most commonly used mp4 format keeping the same crop settings and same audio stream? The purpose is to upload it to youtube with a good resolution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try de-interlacing with the [yadif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif) filter. Command for uploading to YouTube:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -filter:v "yadif,crop=468:374" -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

- It is not possible to filter and [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (`-c:v copy`) the video at the same time. But because the audio is not filtered it can be copied (`-c:a copy`).
- Avoid upscaling. Upscaling is not going to make it have a higher quality. It is not possible to give it higher quality going from small size to big size. It is like magnifying a JPG beyond 1x. It looks bad. Upscaling is doing the same thing because the information is not there to make it look better at a bigger size.

Comment: Q1 - This command makes a .mkv file. If I change it to .mp4, will it make an .mp4 file or we need to add/change parameters?
Q2 - Is it possible to replace few frames of the video with a particular frame within the same command? eg. i want to copy a frame available at 00:00:03 location and paste that fram in duration from 00:00:00 to 00:00:15 range and have this in the same command line
Thanks

Comment: 1) I chose .mkv because you wanted a command for YouTube. .mkv can handle almost any audio format, so it will allow you to stream copy it which will save time and preserve quality. If you want .mp4 instead change `-c:a copy` to `-c:a aac` and `output.mkv` to `output.mp4`. 2) That is a completely different topic that you should post as a new question. Stack Overflow is intended to be 1 question per post, not multiple follow-up questions spanning several topics.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind assistance